# How to loop through "blocks" of rows in excel dataset instead of each row individually (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a data set in Excel where the deciding factors for each block of rows is based on the second column (WO#) because I want to perform calculations (not part of this question) just for items in the same grouping.

[Visualization on iterating through blocks of rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo7ie.jpg)

```
Sub test()
    Dim totalHrs As Integer, lastRow As Integer  
    Dim block As Range, dataSet As Range  

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set dataSet  =  Range("A2:G" & lastRow)

    For Each block In Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Areas    
        'Do calculation stuff
    Next block
End Sub
```

Right now I am having trouble defining what range 'block' should be since it will constantly change. A block begins when the "WO#" column is one number, and the block ends once that column's value changes to something else. How do I go about defining this range?

An easier way would be to just extract rows that have the same WO# into a new table and do the calculations there, but since this dataset can get quite large I would prefer not to do that as the macro will become way too heavy

Comment: What calculations do you want to perform? There may be a simpler (formula-based) solution.

Comment: @BigBen The calculations are a bit convoluted which is why I decided not to include it, but I'm basically creating a timeline for how long it takes to make an item and I have to work backwards from the target delivery date.

e.g. In 1 block:
-the last row: "END" and "DEL-DATE" are equal, "START" is calculated by subtracting "DAYS" from the "END" date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you added this into G11 `=IF(B11=B12,F12,C11)` and then in F11 you added `=G11-E11` and then dragged them down.

It should check to see if it's the last entry in the set and then set itself to the delivery date or set itself equal to the start day of the line below.

Edit:
Try replacing the F11 cell with this `=WORKDAY(G11,-E11)` and dragging down to account for workdays. To account for holidays, you can create a second sheet to list them out as dates and then add them as a range for the third, optional, argument in the Workday function. Please see [the Workday documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.workday) if more clarification is required on the function's use.

Comment: This helps immensely! One last question, how would I go about excluding weekends? Is there a way for me to incorporate the =networkdays() function in this?

Answer (score 0):

The code below defines blocks of similar values in a column. To use this code, either add a column to your worksheet combining columns B and C into one value (`=B11&C11`) or edit the code to check two columns (`If rngCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = rngCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = rngCell.Offset(1, 1).Value Then`). Also, expand the blocks to more than one column.

```
'Starts the first block with the first cell in a column.
Set rngBlock = rngColumn.Cells(1)

'Checks every cell in a column.
For Each rngCell In rngColumn

    'Checks whether a cell's value equals the cell below it.
    If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        Set rngBlock = Union(rngBlock, rngCell.Offset(1, 0))
        'If equal, includes the cell below in the block.
    Else
        'If not equal, does something with the block...
        Debug.Print rngBlock.Address


        'Starts the next block with the cell below.
        Set rngBlock = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next rngCell
```