# Why are there inconsistent and broken cell formulas for some rows and not others?

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal: Populate F and G columns with proper formulas depending on total PROD-TIME for a block**

This is another issue that has come up after one of my previous questions:
[How to loop through "blocks" of rows in excel dataset instead of each row individually (VBA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049524/how-to-loop-through-blocks-of-rows-in-excel-dataset-instead-of-each-row-indivi)

I have been able to loop through blocks of rows and can now get the sum of the PROD-TIME for that particular block. This sum is necessary to determine which formula needs to be used in the F and G columns.

This is best illustrated in this workbook, 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgnqi00h8xosja3/wip%20Gantt%20Template.xlsx?dl=0 , where I have shown how I want the formulas to end up in the F and G columns. But for some reason when I run the macro, it just completely breaks. Some of the formulas don't even use reference cells and use the cell value instead, or reference cells don't even appear. Are the blank F and G columns confusing the macro? How can I make sure that every F and G cell gets filled with something? Errors are fine

```
Sub getStartEndDate()
    Dim WrkSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim RngColumn As Range, RngBlock As Range
    Dim totalHrs As Integer 'total PROD-TIME for the given RngBlock
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set WrkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Populate the last row by itself first since the With-statement below needs to reference rows below current row
    Range("E" & lastRow).Formula = "=ROUNDUP(D" & lastRow & "/12,0)"
    Range("G" & lastRow).Value = Range("C" & lastRow).Value
    Range("F" & lastRow).Formula = "=WORKDAY(G" & lastRow & ", -E" & lastRow & ")"
    Columns("F:F").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

    With WrkSht
        Set RngColumn = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        'Starts the first block with the first cell in a column.
        Set RngBlock = RngColumn.Cells(1)

        'Checks every cell in a column.
        For Each rngcell In RngColumn
            If rngcell.Offset(0,1).Value <> "" Then
                'Checks whether a cell's value equals the cell below it.
                If rngcell.Value = rngcell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                    'If equal, includes the cell below in the block.
                    Set RngBlock = Union(RngBlock, rngcell.Offset(1, 0))
                Else
                    'If not equal, that means the block RngBlock ends
                    ' totalHrs is the sum of the "PROD-TIME" for that particular block
                    totalHrs = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(CStr(Trim(Chr(64 + RngBlock.Column + 2))) _
                                & CStr(Trim(Str(RngBlock.Row))) & ":" _
                                & CStr(Trim(Chr(64 + 2 + RngBlock.Column + RngBlock.Columns.Count - 1))) _
                                & CStr(Trim(Str(RngBlock.Row + RngBlock.Rows.Count - 1)))))

                    If totalHrs < 12 Then
                        ' If total production time (PROD-TIME) is less than 12 hours, then the start and end date should be the same for all rows in that block
                        rngcell.Offset(0, 4).Value = rngcell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        rngcell.Offset(0, 5).Value = rngcell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Else
                        ' If total production time is greater than 12 hours, then start and end dates are based on a different formula 
                        ' e.g. Given row 11, F column formula looks like: =WORKDAY(G11, -E11), G column looks like: =IF(B11=B12,F12,C11) 
                        rngcell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=WORKDAY(" & rngcell.Offset(0, 5) & ", -" & rngcell.Offset(0, 3) & ")"
                        rngcell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=IF(" & rngcell & "=" & rngcell.Offset(1, 0) & "," & rngcell.Offset(1, 4) & "," & rngcell.Offset(0, 1) & ")"
                    End If

                    'Starts the next block with the cell below.
                    Set RngBlock = rngcell.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            End If 

        Next rngcell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Everytime this statement is true : `If totalHrs < 12 Then`, you copy from the column c "`(rngcell.Offset(0, 1).Value)`", but sometimes column c is empty, then you get empty values in col F & G.

Comment: I've edited the statement "if column c is blank, ignore", I forgot I had removed that